# Approximating step functions by Haar wavelets

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, schauder-basis

Let $\psi = \chi_{[0,1/2)} - \chi_{[1/2,1)}$, then $\psi_{n,k}(t) = 2^{n/2}\psi(2^nt-k)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in \{0,1,\dots,2^n-1\}$ defines the Haar-Wavelets on $L^2(0,1)$. Let $S$ be the set of all those Wavelets. I already showed that $S$ is an orthonormal system, which is quite straightforward. To show that they form an orthonormal basis, my idea is the following:

The step functions (functions of the form $\sum_i^N a_i \chi_{Q_i}$ a.e. for $Q_i$ half-open intervals) are dense in $L^2(0,1)$. If I can approximate any function $\chi_{Q_i}$ by a linear combination of Haar-Wavelets I am done, because then we have $\overline{\text{lin } S} = L^2(0,1)$. Since $\text{supp }\psi_{n,k}$ gets arbitrarily small I can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and an index set $I$ such that $\lambda(Q_i \setminus \bigcup_{j \in I} \text{supp }\psi_{N,j}) < \varepsilon$. But I can't find a way to get rid of the parts of this linear combination where it has the value $-1$ in order to get my desired approximation.
Can someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: The Haar wavelets are _not_ an orthonormal basis for $L^2(0,1)$; they're all orthogonal to the constant $1$. If you add the function $1$ to the Haar wavelets you do get an orthonormal basis. One way to prove this is to show that if $f$ is orthogonal to every basis function then $f=0$.

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^1f=0$. Hence (???) $\int_0^{1/2}f=\int_{1/2}^1f=0$. Etc. $\int_If=0$ for every dyadic interval $I$, hence $f=0$ by a certain big theorem.

Comment: Thanks for clarification that the function $1$ is missing, that was not stated in my professors script :/ Yes, I know that another way is to show that $S^\perp = 0$, but my attempt seemed easier to me in the first place. I will try that now, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Probably he just overlooked it because the Haar wavelets _do_ give an orthonormal basis for $L^1(\Bbb R)$ (of course now you need to include rescaled Haar functions "up" as well as "down").

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have to admit no theorem comes to my mind to conclude $f = 0$ a.e.

Comment: You've shown $\int_If=0$ for every dyadic interval $I$? Then the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem implies $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Actually I have never seen that theorem, thats new to me. Thanks for pointing it out.